# Unsure of implementation of Tikz tree with complicated nodes (not just labels)

Tags: tikz-pgf

How would you implement this

[image]

in tikz? So far, I've just done something like this for my trees:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    level distance=3em,
    every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners, draw, align=center},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=7.5em},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=4em},
    level 3/.style={sibling distance=4em},
    level 4/.style={sibling distance=4em}]

    \node{8}
    child { node {5}
        child { node {9} }
        child { node {7}
            child { node {1} }
            child { node {12}
                child { node {2} }
                child [missing]
            }
        }
    }
    child { node {4}
        child[missing]
        child { node {11}
            child { node {3} }
            child[missing]
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and I'm shooting for a solution that is more or less consistent, if possible. The problem I'm running into is how to make the nodes fancier rather than just using labels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach. Using `controls` to draw curved lines and a simple `tabular` for the nodes:

[image]

The code (there is still room for improvement):

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\tnode}[1]{
    \begin{tabular}{l|l}
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{node} \\\hline
        *parent & val=#1
    \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    level distance=7em,
    every node/.style = {align=center, font=\ttfamily, 
        inner sep=0pt, draw, rounded corners,},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=12em, nodes={xshift=5em}},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=12em},
    thick, <-, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt,
    ]
    \node (root) {\tnode{A}} 
        child { node {\tnode{B}}
            [nodes={xshift=-8em}, edge from parent path = 
                {([xshift=-20pt]\tikzparentnode.south) 
                .. controls +(0,-1) and +(-2,1) 
                .. (\tikzchildnode.west)}] 
                child { node{\tnode{E}}}}
        child { node {\tnode{C}} 
            [edge from parent path = 
                {([xshift=0pt]\tikzparentnode.south) 
                .. controls +(0,-1) and +(-1,0) 
                .. (\tikzchildnode.west)}] }
        child { node {\tnode{D}} 
            [nodes={xshift=-5em}, edge from parent path = 
                {([xshift=20pt]\tikzparentnode.south)
                .. controls +(0,-1) and +(-1,1)  
                .. (\tikzchildnode.west)}] 
                child { node {\tnode{F}} 
                    [edge from parent path = 
                     {([xshift=-20pt]\tikzparentnode.south)
                    .. controls +(0,-1) and +(-2,1)  
                    .. (\tikzchildnode.west)}]} 
                child { node {\tnode{G}} 
                    [edge from parent path = 
                     {([xshift=20pt]\tikzparentnode.south)
                    .. controls +(0,-1) and +(-1,0)  
                    .. (\tikzchildnode.west)}]}
                };
    \draw (root.north) to[out=110, in=-180, looseness=3] (root.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not totally happy with this solution but it comes close to what I was trying to do.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    level distance=5em,
    every node/.style = {rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, minimum height=4ex, draw, align=center},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=10em},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=7em},
    level 3/.style={sibling distance=7em},
    level 4/.style={sibling distance=7em},
    level 5/.style={sibling distance=7em},
    thick,<-]

    \node{*parent\nodepart{two}val = A}
    child { node {*parent\nodepart{two}val = B}
        child { node {*parent\nodepart{two}val = E}
            child { node {*parent\nodepart{two}val = H} }
            child { node {*parent\nodepart{two}val = I} }
        }
        child [missing]
    }
    child { node {*parent\nodepart{two}val = C}
    }
    child { node {*parent\nodepart{two}val = D} 
        child { node {*parent\nodepart{two}val = F} 
            child { node {*parent\nodepart{two}val = J} }
            child { node {*parent\nodepart{two}val = K} 
                child { node {*parent\nodepart{two}val = M} }
            }
            child { node {*parent\nodepart{two}val = L} }
        }
        child { node {*parent\nodepart{two}val = G} }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```